# Target content of first element inside element

Tags: jquery, ajax

On `mouseover()`, I target list element `#hello`. Inside that list item, the first element is an  tag **that does not have an ID**, see:

```
<li id="hello">
   <a href="#">0</a>
   <div...
</li>
```

I want to return data inside that `<a>` tag. How do I do this?

```
jQuery( document ).on( 'mouseover', '#hello', function() {
  jQuery.ajax({
    // code condensed
    success:function(data){

        // how do I target the A tag?
        jQuery(this).next().html(data);

    }
  });
});
```

Comment: `jQuery(this).children().first().html(data);`

Comment: @adeneo You got it my friend, post as an answer so I can accept.

Answer (score 0):

Try utilizing `context` of [jQuery.ajax( url [, settings ] )](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-url-settings)

```
jQuery( document ).on( 'mouseover', '#hello', function(e) {
  jQuery.ajax({
    // code condensed
    context: jQuery(e.target).parent().find("a:eq(0)"), // `this` at `success`
    success:function(data){
        // how do I target the A tag?
        jQuery(this).html(data); // `this` : `#hello > a:eq(0)`
    }
  });
});
```

```js
jQuery( document ).on( 'mouseover', '#hello', function(e) {
  jQuery.ajax({
    // code condensed
    url:"https://gist.githubusercontent.com/guest271314/6a76aa9d2921350c9d53/raw/49fbc054731540fa68b565e398d3574fde7366e9/abc.txt",
    type:"GET",
    context: jQuery(e.target).parent().find("a:eq(0)"),
    success:function(data){
        // how do I target the A tag?
        jQuery(this).html(data);

    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li id="hello">
   <a href="#">0</a>
   <div>...</div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work as well. Find first anchor tag with [:first-of-type](http://api.jquery.com/first-of-type-selector/) selector.

```
$(this).find("a:first-of-type").html(data);
```